# Как использовать неявное преобразовние при возвращении Task<T>

Tags: c#

Такой код не работает

```
Task<A> GetA()
{
    return GetB();
}

Task<B> GetB() //не мой метод, я им не владею
{
   ...
}
```

Нельзя неявно преобразовать тип `Task<B>` в тип `Task<A>`. При этом в типе A реализовано неявное преобразование.

```
class A
{   
   public static implicit operator A(B value);
}
```

Я написал так

```
Task<A> GetA()
{
    return GetB().ContinueWith<A>(b => b.Result);
}
```

Работает.

А как-то проще или читаемей можно это сделать?

Comment: `async Task<A> GetA() { return await GetB(); }`. ContinueWith стандартно заменяется async/await.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Вы не поверите, так и было написано. Но я подумал  "зачем тут лишний await?". И тут началось, то что написано в вопросе.

Comment: Мне тоже не нравятся лишние async-await. Но я не знаю, можно ли что-то ещё придумать.